# prevent SearchLookupEdit from closing popup inside repositoryItemLookUpEdit.CloseUp event

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use a `RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit`.
I need to prevent `SearchLookupEdit` from Closing When `PopupCloseMode` is `CloseUpKey`.

```
private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit_CloseUp(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CloseUpEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseMode == PopupCloseMode.CloseUpKey)
        {
            //Prevent from Closing
        }
    }
```

What should I write Instead of `//Prevent from Closing` to Achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can subscribe to [`QueryCloseUp`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupBase_QueryCloseUptopic) event. And check previous pressed key:

```
private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit_QueryCloseUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have trouble with checking previous pressed key. I cant access it from sender or e. How can I check it?

Comment: @HosseinPanahloo you can subscribe to KeyDown or KeyPress event (or override ProcessCmdKey  method) and store last pressed key in some variable, in QueryCloseUp check this variable. Yes, it looks like not good solution, but it works in some cases.